# Conditional with multiple React Components in class render method

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I have a React class with a render method that includes 1 or 3 child components.

If the user is logged out, only the first component should be rendered, and if the user is logged in (or when the user logs in) the second two should also be rendered.

```js
render() {
    return (
        <div className="lists-wrapper {this.data.user}">
            <List title="Featured" tiles={this.data.featured} />
            { this.data.user ?
                <List title="Faves" tiles={this.data.faves} />
                <List title="My Content" tiles={this.data.owned} />
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

However I get the following error:

> Adjacent    JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (58:5)

I can find plenty of documentation and examples of conditionally including one component *or* another, but nothing which helps me in this use-case. Without the conditional, and adding all three of them works as expected.

Comment: I think you forgot to set a colon between the 2 List elements, which makes React think that you return two root elements for one expression and that is considered invalid (https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/maximum-number-of-jsx-root-nodes.html). Strange that it doesn't complain about the messed up expression though.

Comment: I just noticed that as well... ;) But it wasn't the cause of the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap adjacent JSX elements in another element, like div.

Moreover, I will suggest to move the rendering logic to another function to make it clear.

```
/*
 * A simple React component
 */
class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <b>{this.props.title}</b>;
  }
}

class Application extends React.Component {
  renderSection(flag) {
      if(flag) {
        return (<div><List title="Faves"/>
              <List title="My Content"/>
                </div>);  
      }
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="lists-wrapper">
            <List title="Featured" />
            { 
              this.renderSection(true)
            }
        </div>
    );
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been doing that in other components so will refactor this one. I tried wrapping them in another element, but I'd rather not pollute the DOM with additional wrappers if I can avoid it... it all adds up!

Answer (score 0):

`<List title="Featured" tiles={this.data.featured} />`

You can't use the self-closing `/` tag. You must use the `</List>` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this now works if I am only adding one component in the conditional, but when I add two I get the same error...

Comment: { this.data.currentRoomUser ? <List title="Faves" tiles={this.data.faves}></List> <List title="My Content" tiles={this.data.owned}></List> : ''}

Comment: Since you're already in the brackets, I don't think you need to use brackets around the properties, such as `tiles={this.data.faves}`.

Answer (score 0):

As Vivasaayi suggested, moving the logic to another function may be a good idea. However, if you want to have it all in one place, it could look something like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="lists-wrapper {this.data.user}">
            {[
                <List key="featured" title="Featured" tiles={this.data.featured} />,
                this.data.user ?
                    <List key="Faves" title="Faves" tiles={this.data.faves} /> :
                    <List key="MyContent" title="My Content" tiles={this.data.owned} />
            ]}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working now and I've seperated it into another function. I'm getting a warning about adding unique keys, (which I have done), but it's not breaking anything.

Comment: Did you add a unique `key` attribute to every List component? Because now, you are in fact using a list of components, which depends on keys to do efficient virtual dom diffing. Edit: Sorry, you obviously said, that you added key attributes. Forget about it ;)